# update from result of a subquery

Tags: sql

Hi i want upadte a data from the result of a subquery

```
UPDATE A
SET A.a = (select a from A inner join B on B.b=A.c and 
        B.cf='RGNVQE63H48J869P'  and B.b=2345 and
        CAST(A.a as decimal)>1);
```

I want that A.a=result of a subquery.

Comment: You didn't ask a question. What does this code do? Does it not work? Why not? What error do you get? Is the subquery returning multiple rows perhaps? What type of SQL is this on?

Comment: . [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery.  Your code has an issue because the table being updated is repeated in the subquery:

```
UPDATE A
    SET A.a = (SELECT b.a 
               FROM B 
               WHERE B.b = A.c AND 
                     B.cf = 'RGNVQE63H48J869P' AND
                     B.b = 2345 and
                     CAST(A.a as decimal) > 1
              );
```

Notes:

- If the subquery returns more than one row, this will result in an error.
- If the subquery returns no rows, then `0` will be assigned.

This answers the question you have asked here.  If this doesn't do what you really need, ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, an appropriate database tag, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.